# Find closest value in a dict

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, dictionary

So basically I have a dict with some values in it, and I want to find the closest value to the given one. So it would look something like this:

```
values = {"val": [210418, 211120, 211822, 212523, 213500]}
input = 210944
output = find_nearest(input,values["val"])
print output
# 210418
```

and as you can see I want to get the closest value under my value. The min() method was giving me 211120, but I want to get 210418. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values are ordered, like in the example data, this is possible in logarithmic time using bisection:

```
>>> vals = [210418, 211120, 211822, 212523, 213500]
>>> target = 210944
>>> from bisect import bisect_left
>>> i = bisect_left(vals, target)
>>> if i == 0:
...     raise Exception
... 
>>> vals[i-1]
210418
```

If they are not ordered, consider numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(vals)
>>> a[a<target].max()
210418
```

Comment: Loading numpy and bisect like big guns(pun intended) for such a simple problem :P

Comment: @AmitTripathi: `bisect` is a pretty little gun. `numpy` is quite a hefty dependency to pull in for this, though (and returning a NumPy scalar instead of a Python scalar can cause subtle, nasty bugs).

Answer (score 1):

Use `abs(a - b)` as absolute difference (distance) between two values, and pass that as `lambda` to `key` argument of `min` function.

```
  def find_nearest(val, arr):
        return min(arr, key=lambda a: abs(val - a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution. This runs in O(n) time.

```
In [20]: values = {"val": [210418, 211120, 211822, 212523, 213500]}
    ...:

In [21]: list_val = values['val']

In [22]: def nearest_val(val):
    ...:     nearest = list_val[0]
    ...:     for v in list_val[1:]:
    ...:         if v == val:
    ...:             nearest = val
    ...:             break
    ...:         if v-val > 0 and v-val < nearest-val:
    ...:             nearest = v
    ...:     return nearest
    ...:

In [23]: nearest_val(210944)
Out[23]: 210418
```

First sort the "val" list, then loop over the sorted list and keep checking if you have found a value smaller than the nearest calculated till now.

Comment: Sorting takes O(n lg n); the correct answer can be found in O(n) time.

Comment: @chepner you are right. Edited the answer, thanks. Earlier, I was trying to break the loop in mid if found for a better-amortized run-time.

Comment: @ArgusMalware Which specific part is not and how do you decide what's "Pythonic" and what's not?

Comment: @ArgusMalware Revise your definition of Pythonic; it doesn't mean one-liner at the expense of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
values = {"val": [210418, 211120, 211822, 212523, 213500]}
input = 210944
final_value = [i for i in sorted(values['val'], key=lambda x:abs(x-input)) if i < input][0]
```

Output:

```
210418
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the the value `x` whose *positive* difference `input - x` is minimized. Values for which `input - x` is negative can be ignored by letting their key value be `input`, which is by definition larger than `input - x`. Only

```
output = min(values['val'], key=lambda x: input - x if x < input else input)
```

If *no* value is less than `input`, `min` will raise a `ValueError` on the resulting empty sequence. I leave it as an exercise for the reader to decide how to handle that.

Comment: Don't you want to use `abs()`?

Comment: I also misread the question; @wim's answer is the correct one (assuming sorted input).

Comment: OK, I think it's fixed to handle the requirement that the result be no larger than the input.